# AngularJS + d3js: Issues with resizing objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

I'm attempting to integrate AngularJS with d3 for dragging and resizing. I've managed to create a `rect` object that is draggable in an SVG element, and resizable using resize handles. The resize handles work as they should, but resizing is choppy when I try to resize in the north or east direction. I created the following Plunk as a demo of the issue: http://plnkr.co/tG19vpyyw0OHMetLOu2U. (I've simplified it to show the issue I've run into, so there's only one resize handle.)

Dragging works as it should, and resizing in the west and south directions works as well (not shown in the demo).

Figured I'd ask the community and see if anyone had run into this before. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying the `rect` element itself and the enclosing `g` element. There's a very short delay between setting the size of the `rect` and the position of the `g` simply because this has to be done with two separate commands. During this delay, the cursor position relative the the drag rectangle changes, firing a new `drag` event with values that correspond to the inconsistent intermediate state. This is fixed immediately afterwards (as soon as the attributes of both elements have been adjusted) and a new  `drag` event is fired that fixes the inconsistency, but it is noticeable as a flicker.

The easiest way to fix this is to change both size and position for the `rect` and nothing for the `g` element. This means adjusting the position of the drag rectangle as well and makes the code less nice, but avoids the timing/inconsistency problem.

So `myrect` becomes

```
var myRect = d3.select(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect"))
            .attr("data-ng-width", "{{square.w}}")
            .attr("data-ng-height", "{{square.h}}")
            .attr("stroke", "yellow")
            .attr("stroke-width", 3)
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
            .attr("data-ng-x", "{{square.x}}")
            .attr("data-ng-y", "{{square.y}}");
```

and `resizer`

```
var resizer = myGroup.append("rect")
            .attr("width", 5)
            .attr("height", 5)
            .attr("stroke", "blue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
            .attr("cursor", "nw-resize")
            .attr("x", "{{square.x-2.5}}")
            .attr("y", "{{square.y-2.5}}")
            .call(nresize);
```

I've updated your code with this solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXN3srhRDMXttRkBmP3w?p=preview).

Comment: I see that this is working - however, I see that on the drag function, you're also changing the width and height of the rectangle? I'm trying to fully understand the implications of the code you've written here (as I'll have to include other elements in the group that will have to move along with the rectangle). Additionally....you said that the delay is causing the issue? If I were able to find a way to defer the execution, would that fix the issue?

Comment: No, the fundamental issue is the disconnect between setting the attributes of the two related objects I believe. You should be able to put `myrect` inside a group with other elements (but not `resizer`) without problems.

Comment: How is it that the `transform` property of the group and the x/y coordinates of the square are both set to the angular value? I'm sure I tried that before and ran into issues with the drag function not working correctly (as the group x/y and the rect x/y were getting added together). (This is why, originally, I fixed the rectangle coordinates to 0,0.) I guess I understand that this works, but I'm trying to figure out what you did and what I didn't do.

Comment: I'm not actually changing the transform coordinates of the group anymore -- sorry, probably should have made that explicit.

Comment: Ah, whoops, just noticed that the `attr` call was commented out! That makes a lot more sense. I'm anticipating having to have objects within the group, though (like, an object name centered in the square or circle) and a rotation handle as well (as this is what's defined by my project spec). I figured that applying transforms to a single coordinate space made the most sense, but maybe that's not the case.

Comment: It's certainly conceptually the cleanest way, it just doesn't work well in practice :)

Comment: This did end up being the way to go, and I was still able to apply a rotational transform to the group element without issues. Thank you.